# How to log deployments with New Relic on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, newrelic

I'm using the New Relic addon on a Django/Python Heroku app and I would like to log deployments, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Heroku offers [an HTTP POST deploy hook](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks#http-post-hook), but it seems to be too restrictive to match the requirements for the New Relic REST API: it requires a `x-api-key` header and the parameter names don't match ([see here for details](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/applications-dashboards/deployments-dashboard)).

I haven't been able to find any information about this anywhere. Am I missing something? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should happen automatically, but NewRelic deployment tracking integration with Heroku has been broken since approx Nov 1st.

I have a support ticket open on this issue and it should be fixed sometime in the next week or so.

**EDIT (11/23/2013):**

Heroku acknowledged this is a bug caused by an overhaul of the NewRelic addon.  Here's what they said as root cause on my support ticket:

> I've got an update on this, but no resolution yet. To give you some context (given you've asked how this has happened 3 times) New
>   Relic were the very first add-on in the Marketplace and as a result
>   there has been a lot of gnarly code very specific to their
>   implementation. On their side they've also had to . And as you've
>   gathered unfortunately much of it was not well tested. We've been
>   working with New Relic all year to finally fix that, and we've moved
>   them across to the standard API that all other add-ons and most PaaS
>   providers now adhere to. Any new customers since May have been on that
>   new integration so we've been testing it out for 6 months. The final
>   part of that process was to remove customers on the legacy integration
>   and that occurred as part of the migration onto the new pricing we
>   announced at the start of this month.
>
> It's only after this migration we realized there was no support for deploy notifications. 
>   New customers since may had never been exposed to the feature so
>   didn't notice it was missing, and it appears none of the legacy
>   customers we tested with in October noticed it was missing either. To
>   rectify the situation we've had to try and build this feature out in
>   the Add-ons API. That's been documented and deployed, and we're now
>   working with New Relic to help their engineers implement it as soon as
>   they possibly can.

I don't think you can view my support ticket, but you're welcome to reference it with Heroku if you file your own ticket:

https://help.heroku.com/tickets/102722

**EDIT (01/06/2014):**

NewRelic/Heroku appear to have fixed their integration so that deploys are now being tracked successfully.  This appears to have gone into effect sometime on/before 1/2/2014.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a publicly visible page about the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of.  The support ticketing system is locked, private to the account filing it.  I'll try to update this when it's fixed.

Comment: @Winfield anything new?

Comment: Deployment tracking is still broken, I heard from an engineer the back-story on what's going on.  I'll update the original answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Let's hope they get this working again soon.

Comment: Not sure best way to notify folks, but the integration appears fixed.  I've updated the answer here with details.